# Url helper is not available when rendering a partial from a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a helper class that renders a partial to store the content in the database.

It works fine but when the view contains a url provided by the url helper

```
<%= link_to "Show project", projects_url, class: "button" %>
```

it throws the following exception

undefined local variable or method projects_url for #

The code to render in my helper named NotificationRender is

```
def render(options)
    viewer = ActionView::Base.new()
    viewer.view_paths = ActionController::Base.view_paths
    viewer.extend ApplicationHelper    
    viewer.render options
end
```

I include this helper in a class Notification

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  include NotificationRender

  .....
  def self.create_for(user, event, params)   
      template = "notifications/_email_project"
      list_params = {:template => template,:locals => params}
      notification = Notification.new
      notification.message = notification.render(list_params) #here I render the partial
      notification.subject = I18n.t "subject.#{event}"
      notification.to = user.email     
      notification.save
 end

end
```

Comment: You may have to include the URL helper in your render helper